# how can we require node_module in out chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, node-modules, browser-extension

how can we require node_module in out chrome extension?....because Trying to require() a package means that node will try to locate its files in your file system. A chrome extension only has access to the files you declare in the manifest, not your filesystem. so how is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Using a bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) can solve your issue (if your packages do not contain any binaries). It requires a bit of configuration if you have different endpoints (content_scripts, background page, popup, etc.).
Libs such as [webpack-extension-reloader](https://github.com/rubenspgcavalcante/webpack-extension-reloader) also helps a lot.